# PHP PDO and MySQL AGAINST() function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**MySQL version: 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1**

I have a query that runs

`MATCH(title) AGAINST('+:word_1 :word_2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

I am unable to get it to honor the PDO parameters.  I have attempted formatting it with '`?`' placeholders as well with no success.

As soon as I run plaintext, the query runs fine:

```
MATCH(title) AGAINST('+cat hat' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

PDO parameters are my preferred method of making sure incoming text in the database is safe, and I would love to have this work, if for nothing else, consistency.

Any recommendations?

Comment: PDO can't bind inside quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

then

```
$stmt->execute([ '+' . $word_1 . ' ' . $word_2 ]);
```

In other words, you concatenate `'+'` , `$word_1` , and `$word_2` together and bind that entire string.

Comment: I was under the impression that everything sent in the `AGAINST` had to be in quotes.  Concatenation is the perfect solution. Cheers

Comment: @cjaredrun, yes, it does when it is a string.  But when you bind a string in a prepared statement, the quotes will be added automatically.

Comment: that makes all the sense in the world.